# Got "Failure to initialize security context" in python thrift client access HBase Thrift Server (with kerberos)

Tags: python, hbase, kerberos, thrift

I followed [this guide](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Start-and-test-HBASE-thrift-server-in-a-kerberised/ta-p/244670) to setup an HBase Thrift server in my kerberized cluster, and tried to follow these guidelines to access it from python: https://blog.csdn.net/gongbi917/article/details/52795232
(Chinese version - https://cloud.tencent.com/developer/article/1436986)

I have a very simple sample python code, which try to connect to secured HBase Thrift server.

```
from thrift.transport import TSocket
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from hbase import Hbase
from hbase.ttypes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socket = TSocket.TSocket('host001.test.com', 9090)
    transport = TTransport.TSaslClientTransport(socket, 'host001.test.com','hbase')
    transport.open()
    protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(transport)
    client = Hbase.Client(protocol)
    print(client.getTableNames())
```

But I get below error:

`thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Bad SASL negotiation status: 3 (b'Failure to initialize security context')`

Any one knows the root cause for this error?

Comment: My hbase cluster have similar settings as this link: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Start-and-test-HBASE-thrift-server-in-a-kerberised/ta-p/244670

Comment: You might wanna look at happybase (https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and its `happybase-sasl` package specifically http://pydoc.net/happybase-sasl/1.0/